# What does this pronunciation 'yeh'll' imply?

Tags: pronunciation

> "Call me Hagrid," he said, "everyone does. An' like I told yeh, I'm
>   Keeper of Keys at Hogwarts -- **yeh'll** know all about Hogwarts, o'
>   course. 
>    "Er -- **no**," said Harry. 
>    Hagrid looked
>   shocked. 
>    "Sorry," Harry said quickly. 
>    "Sorry?" barked
>   Hagrid, turning to stare at the Dursleys, who shrank back into the
>   shadows. "It's them as should be sorry! I knew yeh weren't gettin' yer
>   letters but I never thought yeh wouldn't even know abou' Hogwarts, fer
>   cryin' out loud! Did yeh never wonder where yet parents learned it
>   all?"
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

It’s not like ‘yeh’ll’ is a future tense, because of the next reply, ‘no.’ So it seems a dialect for ‘you all’ or ‘you already’ ,etc. What does the pronunciation imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bill Franke says, the odd spelling reflects a non- or sub-standard pronunciation, not a distinct meaning.

The use of *will* here (contracted to *'ll*) does not imply futurity but certainty. I fancy (but have no authority at all for asserting) that it derives from the use of *will* in the consequence clause of conditional constructions:

> If you add one and one you'll get two.

This expression is often (but not in this case) a polite way of asking a Yes/No question where you wish (however ironically) to avoid suggesting that the answer might be No. For instance:

> No doubt you'll be familiar with Prof. Sartorius' treatment of this matter.

This amounts to saying "Since it would reflect badly on you if you were **not** familiar with this work, I assume that if I ask, you **will** be familiar with it."

Comment: Thank you very much: Even my mother tongue was confused after reading your answer. Yes, it also has the same implying; not futurity but certainty with future post-position. One of the big benefits from a leaning foreign language is to ponder more about my own.

Comment: @Listenever  That's why many of us are here: because these questions make us see our own language with new eyes.

Answer (score 6):

It's just the writer's attempt at capturing Hagrid's accent. It **implies** nothing other than that he doesn't speak RP ([received pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)). It **means** "You will".